# Massive UDP packet loss in the sleep mode

Tags: android, udp, wifi

There is Android native app, which send about 10 UDP packets per second over WiFi connection. Packets are very small (3-4 bytes each) and they are **not** multicast (directed to antother host in the same subnet).

So, problem good seen on the following graphs.

1. [Normal operation while android device in the active state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGa56.png)
2. [After device screen was muted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o6pa.png)
   (time between splaches ~5 sec, splash duration ~0.5 s, but periodicity is not ideal)
3. [If in parallel perform ping of android device from third host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNzot.png)

**WifiLock on the device is acquired, but this nothing change at all.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. As it turned out, it's not about packets loss. Due to CPU sleep, transmitter send packets not as solid stream and result was look like a massive loss. So solution is usage of [WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock).